# how to find machine is part of another environment in microsoft test manager

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I am not able to create environment in mtm. Because of the is already part of another environment. Please help me to find machine is part of another environment in microsoft test manager

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to understand and answer too!

Comment: Which environment are trying to create? Standard or SCVMM? Which error message are you getting?

Comment: I was creating Standard environment but i am not able to connect.

Comment: Error msg is "Agent could not connect to controller"

Comment: @IndrajeetGaikwad If the problem is a machine being already in another environment, can't you visually skim the list of environments in the Lab section of Lab Center and see if the machine appears more than once there? How many environments do you have?